# Invalid authorisation linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I want to copy data from 1 table to another and they are in different servers.

I have set 2 servers as linked servers. In SQL Server Management Studio,

- Server Objects

  - Right-click Linked Servers,
  - and then New linked server.

I gave the connecting server as my serve rname SERVER2 and type as SQLSERVER.

Now I execute the query:

```
Insert Into Server1.Database1.dbo..Table1 (Col1, Col2) 
     Select Col1, Col2 
       From Server2.Database2..dbo.Table2
```

It is throwing an error message,

> The OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "SERVER2" has returned the message "Invalid authorization specification".

I have no idea where to change the authorization.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In SSMS, Server Objects -> Linked Servers, Right-click on SERVER2 and choose Properties.

In the properties window, click on "Security" in the left hand panel.

In the section labeled, "For a login not defined in the list above, connections will:", choose the last option "Be made using this security context:". Then specify a login and password for an account on Server2 with appropriate permissions for the task you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Now the error is "An invalid schema or an invalid catalog was specified for the provider "SQLNCLI" for linked server "CTRZSQL.". still not able to copy the data..

Comment: If the syntax in your original post is accurate and not just a typo, then you have two periods between "Database2" and "DBO" where you should only have one: Server2.Database2.dbo.Table2

Comment: I have modified that to Insert Into SERVER1.DB1.TBL1(F1)
Select F1 From SERVER2.DB2.TBL2. Then it is throwing an error message Invalid object name SERVER2.DB2.TBL2.
Something that is strange for me, when i queried this way it is copy data from other Server->Db->TBL.
Insert Into TBL1(F1)
Select * from openquery(LINKEDSEREVERNAME,'Select concession from DBNAME..TBLNAME'). Can you please explain me why?

Comment: You still need to fully qualify your tables with an appropriate 4-tuple in the form of: ServerName.DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName

Comment: Do you mean in the query or..? Can you please explain in detail, where i need to specify this 4-tuple?

Comment: I mean in the query. Your original posted syntax should work once you remove the double periods.  Insert Into Server1.Database1.dbo.Table1 (Col1, Col2) Select Col1, Col2 From Server2.Database2.dbo.Table2

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working for me..It is throwing me an error message:- Invalid object name SERVER2.DB2.TBL2. Do i need to modify any settings??

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you need to fully qualify with a 4-tuple. Your example of SERVER2.DB2.TBL2 is only a 3-tuple which is missing the Schema name. Assuming the default DBO schema, you should be using SERVER2.DB2.DBO.TBL2.

Comment: Thanks for ur patience. I think, Default schema used by SQL Server when objects are created by a database owner and a schema is not identified. Is there any other way to identify them?

Comment: DBO is the default schema. This query should help you identify the schema for a given table: select s.name as SchemaName 
 from sys.tables t
  inner join sys.schemas s
   on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
 where t.name = 'YourTableName'